# How to remove duplicate data lines with data not in came columns

Tags: sql

A `SELECT QUERY` for Person Matches produces a Table in which each 2nd line contains the same info as the line above it.
After a `Sort By Surname,GivenName,BirthD`
e.g.

```
IDIR1, Surname, GivenName, BirthD IDIR2. 
IDIR2, Surname, GivenName, BirthD IDIR1.
```

(Both persons have the same criteria but diff `IDIR`)

What options are there to eliminate the appearence of the 2nd Lines. 
Delete is acceptable but `NOT IN, <>,` etc. do not work because:
All `IDIRs (1 & 2)` are in the `2 IDIR` columns. 
Only one line is read to check if both are Individuals & not Same Person.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Something along theese lines should give you a result set where every second record has been left out.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM thetable AS a
  JOIN thetable AS b
    ON a.Surname = b.Surname
   AND a.GivenName = b.GivenName
   ...
 WHERE a.IDIR < b.IDIR
```

Note that it is untested - you may need to clean it up a little bit, but the trick is using `a.IDIR < b.IDIR` to weed out the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks heaps @mzedeler - it worked a charm. Only had to add the last line to my SELECT Query as an AND to the 7 other filters.The Data Base is Access within Legacy Genealogy with LTools as Query editor.